# How to signify which table a certain row comes from?

Tags: mysql, select

Say I was pulling columns from three unique tables in a sql query. And say those columns have the same datatype. Is there a way I could have an extra column in my results that would signify which table a certain row came from? Like 1 for table_A, 2 from table_B, etc. How would I do that?

Comment: Using alias on your selected fields ?

Comment: Are you using UNION's?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT "table1" which, colX the_col
FROM table1
WHERE ...
UNION
SELECT "table2" which, colY the_col
FROM table2
WHERE ...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select A.col as col_A, B.col as col_B from A join B;
```